# How do I edit my table in design view?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have tried to change the primary key for my table in SQL server management studio, but it kept telling me that visual studio had a connection with it and I can not save any changes.

I tried to close visual studio and i even checked my task manager for any processes that may be using  visual studio but there was nothing, it just did not allow me to change anything I basically had to create a new table cause of this.

Comment: broken_code you do realize you can just update it by right clicking it and selecting script table as create to new query editor window from there you change the create table to update and boom there you go working with the script is alot more functional as you can drop the table keep the script ,change it as you wish and then recreate the exact same table i find this preferable to the design view

Comment: To whomever down-voted my question I want to know why and what I should do to fix whatever I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Tools >> Options >> Designers >> remove the check of the option (Prevent saving changes that requires table re-creation)

Comment: Ok how can i do the recreation process i mean just in future or if i happen to be on someone-elses system

Comment: Of course you can check it and it will prevent the saving operation, then you will have to delete and create the table, you can always create a script of your tables (right click on the table >> script table as >> create to >> New query editor window

Comment: i said that lol but meh im glad you found the solution to your problem just a tip use script its better than the designer and you will thank me for it later ,hard code thumps shortcut designers everytime as i have said in the comment above

Comment: @Wolf: it is not that I do not find your answer useful and I just did not understand it.

Comment: @Broken_Code if you script your table you can modify it there namely say  your changing your table column if you do it in the code you can drop it with code drop table table-name  and then just recreate the exact table by executing the code or change the create at the top to update this is more efficient than the design view p.s il upvote your question because it is a valid one

Comment: IF you uncheck the property you will be able to edit the table design and save it without the need of drop it and create it again... and if you check the property you will not be able to save your modification on table design, you will NEED to Drop the table and create new one with the new design

Comment: @Wolf: Ok so even with the script I have to use the drop function I can not just change my script with the new column am i understanding you correctly?

Comment: yes you have it right but by doing it this way you will save time ,it is also possible to use UPDATE but that will depend on if you are allowed to update and if other programs are using your table,what relationships your table has and so on but this way you can do it all from 1 point instead of deleting and then going to design creating all the columns over etc

Comment: When you apply any modification on the table design, SQL will notify and inform the user of the modification effects on related tables

Answer (score 1):

Here let me explain  here you can change ,add ,basically modify your table as you wish then execute drop table and just execute the create table again

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestUserInfo](
[UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SubscriberName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CompanyName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[TelephoneContact] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_TestUserInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
[UserID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

  SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
  GO

   drop table TestUserInfo
```

if you are allowed you can change the Create to Update

```
   UPDATE TABLE [dbo].[TestUserInfo](
[UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SubscriberName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CompanyName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[TelephoneContact] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestUserInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
[UserID] ASC
     )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

     GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
```

instead of going through the whole process in the design view you can do everything here

Comment: If i had two scripts one with create and one with update and i basically only used update for the changes and if the changes made were permanent would i be able to overwrite the create table from sql server with these changes if so what kind of impact would that have on the new tables being created say on different computer systems

Comment: lol slow down hahaha update rarely works because sql is a fickle woman if you use the drop and create method it will be faster by far and only work with 1 script you can do everything with it by simply changing it to what you want ,the script above i simply inserted update where create stood change it as you wish i would suggest reading up on update to fully understand it ,a table with data in might give you trouble so plan carefully

Comment: hope i helped if you need a better explanation let me know and we can take this to discussion

Comment: I will I am new to all this just got thrown in the deep end unfortunately so yeah. That is why I am asking, Yes it is very informative I know a lot more now than 20 minutes ago

Comment: lol completely understandable i am in a similar situation but with web-sockets it sucks but in the end a person will come out better for it .aah your question is 1 vote up ;)

Comment: if you need help in sql let me know Broken_code il help where i can and when i have available time